# How do I use the Redmine REST API over https from .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, redmine

Our internal Redmine server only allows me to connect via HTTPS. Here's how I tried to use the REST API via HTTPS from .NET:

1. As suggested in *[Using the REST API with .NET](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api_with_csharp)*, setting the host variable to `"https://redmine.company.com/redmine/"` and the apiKey to `"ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"`.
2. From scratch with the following code:

   ```
   using System.IO;
   using System.Net;

   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, error) => true;

           var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
               "https://redmine.company.com/redmine/issues/149.xml?key=ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff");
           request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
           request.Method = "GET";

           using (var response = request.GetResponse()) // Hangs here
           using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
           using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
           {
               responseStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Of course, `company.com` and `ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff` are just placeholders for my real company and my real API key on my account page. Both attempts hang for some time before timing out with a WebException (see the *Hangs here* comment in attempt 2). I then tried to download other stuff from the Redmine server (like e.g. time_entries.csv, atom feeds, etc.), each time with exactly the same result.

So far so bad. However, if I copy-paste the URL `https://redmine.company.com/redmine/issues/149.xml?key=ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff` into my browser, I get exactly the response I would expect. So, it seems as though our Redmine server behaves as it should, but somehow I can't get it to work from .NET.

I have successfully downloaded stuff from other HTTPS sites and have managed to download issue data from http://demo.redmine.org with the code of attempt 2 (of course with adapted URLs, etc.). So, it seems there might be something special about how Redmine communicates over HTTPS.

If anybody is successfully using the Redmine REST API over HTTPS from .NET, I'd be really grateful for some pointers on what I'm doing wrong.

Also, suggestions on how to debug this from the client side would be greatly appreciated. So far I've tried Fiddler2, with no success. As soon as I enable its "Decrypt HTTPS traffic" setting then I no longer get an answer when I make the request in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

We use [redmine-net-api](http://code.google.com/p/redmine-net-api/) which supports HTTP/S connection and authentication based on API keys.

```
        RedmineManager rm = new RedmineManager("https://<your-address>", <api-key>, "random-password");
        IList<Issue> issues = rm.GetObjectList<Issue>(new NameValueCollection() { { "project_id", <project-id> } });
```

Comment: I've just tried with your code, replacing <your-address>, <api-key> and <project-id>. I get exactly the same result (timeout) as with my other attempts. Are you using the API over https? Thanks!

Comment: Hey Do you succeeded in getting the result.If i try this im getting tasks with name other than the one given in the parameter list             IList<Issue> issues = manager.GetObjectList<Issue>(new NameValueCollection() { { "tracker_name", "Client Requests" } });

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me:

```
// Allow every secure connection
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, error) => true;

// Create redmine manager (where URL is "https://10.27.10.10/redmine" for me and redmineKey is my redmine API key
RedmineManager redmineManager = new RedmineManager(redmineURL, redmineKey);

// Create your query parameters
NameValueCollection queryParameters = new NameValueCollection { { "project_id", "4" }, {"tracker_id", "17"}, { "offset", "0" } };

// Perform your query
int issuesFound = 0;
foreach (var issue in redmineManager.GetObjectList<Issue>(queryParameters, out issuesFound))
{
// By default you get the 25 first issues of the project_id and tracker_id specified.
// Play with the offset to get the rest
queryParameters["offset"] = ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Explicit passing `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` value for `securityProtocolType` parameter solved the problem for my case:

```
RedmineManager redmineManager = new RedmineManager(_host, _apiKey, 
    securityProtocolType: SecurityProtocolType.Tls12);
```